# combine two collections together in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a `$sizes` collection like this :

```
$sizes =
            collect([
                10 => 'xl',
                11 => 'xxl',
                12 => 'xxxl'
            ]);
```

And a `$colors` collection like this :

```
$colors =
            collect([
                20 => 'red',
                21 => 'green',
                22 => 'blue'
            ]);
```

Now I want to create a combination of those like this :

```
$result =
            collect([
                [10 => 'xl' , 20 => 'red'],
                [10 => 'xl' , 21 => 'green'],
                [10 => 'xl' , 22 => 'blue'],
                [11 => 'xxl' , 20 => 'red'],
                [11 => 'xxl' , 21 => 'green'],
                [11 => 'xxl' , 22 => 'blue'],
                [12 => 'xxxl' , 20 => 'red'],
                [12 => 'xxxl' , 21 => 'green'],
                [12 => 'xxxl' , 22 => 'blue']
            ]);
```

How can I do that in laravel ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-crossjoin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a crossJoin operation.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-crossjoin

Comment: Does it save the keys?